# how can I call batch command multiple times until success?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that calls various commands, some of which will occasionally fail due to network issues. Re-trying the command will usually result in success.

How can I re-try the commands automatically, up to a set number of tries?

Here is the some pseudo code that aims to explain further

```
call:try numTries "command and arguments"
exit

:try
REM execute %2, trying upto %1 times if it fails
%1 = %1 -1
eval %2
if %errorlevel%==0 exit \B
if %1 > 0 goto try
exit \B
```

Comment: @Preet Sangha Apologies, I'm having a bad day. Question updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following script be be what you are looking for:

```
CALL :try numTries "command and arguments"
GOTO :EOF


:try
SET /A tries=%1

:loop
IF %tries% LEQ 0 GOTO return

SET /A tries-=1
EVAL %2 && (GOTO return) || (GOTO loop)

:return
EXIT /B
```

The logic of the `try` sub-routine is this:

1. Store the number of tries into a variable.
2. Begin the loop. Check the `tries` variable. If 0 or less, return.
3. Evaluate the command and arguments.
4. If the returned value is 'success' (ERRORLEVEL is 0), return (from the `try` routine), otherwise go to #2 (the beginning of the loop).

Comment: One change was required from the answer: eval is not available. Instead I used `%2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9`. Nasty but I don't see another way of doing it

Answer (score 5):

without eval and > (pretty much copy pasta of MatsT's answer)

```
REM execute %2, trying upto %1 times if it fails
set count=%1
set command=%2
:DoWhile
    if %count%==0 goto EndDoWhile
    set /a count = %count% -1
    call %command%
    if %errorlevel%==0 goto EndDoWhile
    if %count% gtr 0 goto DoWhile
:EndDoWhile
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
call:try numTries "command and arguments"
exit

:try
    REM execute %2, trying upto %1 times if it fails
    set count = %1
    set command = %2
    :DoWhile
        if %count%==0 goto EndDoWhile
        set count = %count% -1
        eval %command%
        if %errorlevel%==0 goto EndDoWhile
        if %count% > 0 goto DoWhile
    :EndDoWhile
exit \B
```

EnableDelayedExpansion is a way to evaluate variables at execution time rather than at parse time. Without it there is no way to keep count updating in a loop. Otherwise most of the code looks to already be working. I wouldn't recommend updating the argument variables themselves as it's usually safer and less confusing to start the function by copying them into other variables.

Comment: There is no need to use delayed expansion, if you use set /a. Parentheses count as one line, so variable expansion is irrelevant without parenthnses or formula. In addition, set /a always delays expansion.

Answer (score -1):

The zombie arises.

Consider just using:

```
START /wait "command and arguments"
```

Comment: That doesn't really solve the problem at all, does it? It runs the command for sure, but it will not retry on failure?